# Sites load balancing on IIS with single server

Tags: iis, load-balancing, arr

I have a particular use case where I need to do a load balancing between my sites on IIS (Not multiple servers).
For that I was referring to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/web-hosting/scenario-build-a-web-farm-with-iis-servers/configuring-step-3-configure-iis-web-farm-load-balancing).
As You can see below I have 3 Web sites on which I'm willing to do the load balancing:

[image]

I have setup the AAR and created a farm, but how do I add my different web sites (Not servers) ?
Is it possible with the AAR ? Or do I need to do it otherwise?

Comment: When people say load balancing or server farms, they are talking about multiple servers. So your question itself is invalid, and your attempt won't give much help on high availability.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to know load balance is used for one site, not multiple sites. One site deploy on multiple servers to enable receive more and more requests. Load balance server is used to forward these requests to server which don't have too much requests need to handle.

Second web farm is composed of multiple servers. In the beginning of docs **Build a Web Farm with IIS Servers** it has indicated that you need have administrator access to at least **five** computers (or virtual machines) that run the Windows Server operating system.
[image]

So you don't need to set ARR for these 3 sites.